# Is Javascript already reactive?

Tags: javascript, java, rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

Reactive programming is programming paradiagm which deals with working with data streams. For java i can say that we can have RxJava and make java reactive like having events etc. **But my question is why do we need RxJS for javascript, we already have events for javascript it makes Javascript reactive. So is it safe to say that Reactive programming is for making other languages behave like javascript?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are attributing DOM events to javascript. A browser runs javascript but it is the browser that acts upon event like click etc. The function setTimeOut for example is also not a javascript thing. It is the browser's.

So no, I don't think it is safe to say that RxJava / RxPhp etc is trying to mimic javascript behavior.